# Only get IPv4 address without the "IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . :" in bat-file

Tags: batch-file, command, ip-address

I will create a little batch file to copy my IP address directly to my clipboard. I have tried:

```
@echo off
ipconfig | find "IPv4" | clip
pause
```

But gives me: `IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.xx.xx`. Is there a way to only get `192.168.xx.xx`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%a in ('ping -n 1 -4 ""') do echo %%a | clip
```

- Execute a `ping` command to local machine (`""`), sending only one packet (`-n 1`) using ipv4 (`-4`)
- The output of the `ping` command is processed inside a `for /f` command
- The first line in the `ping` output includes the ip address enclosed in square brackets
- The `for /f` tokenizes the line using the square brackets as delimiters, and retrieve the second token

```
                         v       v          (delimiters)
    Pinging computername [x.x.x.x] with 32 bytes of data
    1                     2       3             (tokens)
```

Answer (score 3):

This batch file can did the trick and can also give you the MAC Address too if you want of course !

```bat
@echo off
Title Get IP and MAC Address
@for /f "delims=[] tokens=2" %%a in ('ping -4 -n 1 %ComputerName% ^| findstr [') do (
    set "MY_IP=%%a"
)

@For /f %%a in ('getmac /NH /FO Table') do  (
    @For /f %%b in ('echo %%a') do (
        If /I NOT "%%b"=="N/A" (
            Set "MY_MAC=%%b"
        )
    )
)
echo Network IP : %MY_IP%
echo MAC Address : %MY_MAC%
pause>nul & exit
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I have created a batch file. you can clip it out as per your requirement.

```
@echo off
ipconfig | findstr /R /C:"IPv4 Address"
pause
```

You can see the output of the batch file here...

[image]

Comment: The question already shows your solution, and the OP searches a solution WITHOUT the `IPv4 Address` prefix

Comment: If you try to answer a question (in this case the question is one ear old and has two good answers), your solution should at least solve the problem and if there are already solutions it should be better or at least different

Answer (score -1):

Javascript (Node) version :

```
const cp =      require( 'child_process' );
let ipCmd =     `ipconfig | findstr /R /C:"IPv4 Address"`;
let ip =        cp.execSync( ipCmd ).toString( );
let returnIp =  /IPv4 Address\./i.test( ip ) 
                   ? ip.match( /\.\s\.\s\.\s:\s([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})/ )[1]
                   : 'facked';

console.log( returnIp );
```

Comment: The question is about batch-files, it's off topic to use different languages or it would end up in hundreds of answers for any language